# How to save bulk data with some conditiond

Tags: apex, soql, rest-api, json

i want to save following JSON data to "myObject__c". suppose i have already "test1@gmail.com" and "test3@gmail.com" in my salesforce object. So how can i save following data in "myObject__c" except these two records.

my JSON data:

```
{"products":[{
"id":"100",
"name":"test1",
"email":"test1@gmail.com",
"created_at":"2015-11-19T23:12:45Z",
"updated_at":"2016-04-08T20:37:12Z"
}, {
"id":"101",
"name":"test1",
"email":"test1@gmail.com",
"created_at":"2015-11-19T23:12:45Z",
"updated_at":"2016-04-08T20:37:12Z"
}, {
"id":"102",
"name":"test2",
"email":"test2@gmail.com",
"created_at":"2015-11-19T23:12:45Z",
"updated_at":"2016-04-08T20:37:12Z"
}, {
"id":"103",
"name":"test3",
"email":"test3@gmail.com",
"created_at":"2015-11-19T23:12:45Z",
"updated_at":"2016-04-08T20:37:12Z"
}, {
"id":"104",
"name":"test4",
"email":"test4@gmail.com",
"created_at":"2015-11-19T23:12:45Z",
"updated_at":"2016-04-08T20:37:12Z"
},
]}
```

my APEX code is:

```
myObject__c[] itemToCreate = new myObject__c[]{};
    for(WooOrderModel order : orderList){

        myObject__c singleOrder = new myObject__c(
            id = id,
            name = name,
            email = email,
            created_at = created_at,
            updated_at = updated_at
            );
        itemToCreate.add(singleOrder);
    }
insert itemToCreate;
```

But this code save all the data. i am looking some dynamic solution. Please help me

Comment: Is email a External Id field in your custom object?

Comment: yes make email a unique field. And it wouldn't insert the records.

Comment: Looking at your profile, it seems you already have a solution for deserializing the JSON (and storing in an Apex class in-memory). If that's true, the focus of this question is then how to filter out some of the `WooOrderModel` records to prevent them from being inserted.

Comment: thanks for your comment. actually my question not about "eserializing the JSON". my question is how to prevent duplicate record inserting. and tried it by  unique field but when i try to save Apex generate some  "unique field eoor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a general solution, then we need to do 2 things:

1. Determine which emails already exist in `myObject__c` records
2. Either prevent inserting records, with existing emails, into your `itemToCreate` list, or remove them from your list before inserting.

To take care of thing #1, I'd suggest building a collection (`set`, `list`, or `map`) to hold emails that you've come across as you build the `myObject__c` records. That means we'll selectively remove `myObject__c` items from the collection before inserting.

Assuming your provided JSON is correct and a given email can show up more than once, a `Map<String, List<myObject__c>>` would be appropriate here.

Using that, your code would become

```
Map<String, List<myObject__c>> emailsToObjects = new Map<String, List<myObject__c>>();
for(WooOrderModel order : orderList){

    // assuming that order has id, name, email, etc... attributes
    // id must be a custom field, since Salesforce Ids are 15-18 characters long
    // created_at and updated_at must also be custom fields because
    //  createdDate and lastModifiedDate can't really be set directly
    myObject__c singleOrder = new myObject__c(
        id__c = order.id,
        name = order.name,
        email__c = order.email,
        created_at__c = order.created_at,
        updated_at__c = order.updated_at
        );

    // Check to see if we've previously encountered this email address.
    // If not, we need to put it into our map, along with a new, empty, list
    // to hold myObject__c records
    if(!emailsToObjects.containsKey(order.email)){
        emailsToObjects.put(order.email, new List<myObject__c>());
    }
    emailsToObjects.get(order.email).add(singleOrder);
}
```

At this point, we can get the set of emails we need to check by calling `emailsToObjects.keySet()`.

The next part is to run a query to see which of these emails are already in `myObject__c`

```
// We could 'GROUP BY email' in the query below. Doing that would avoid
// excess iterations of the for loop, but the situations in which this would
// help are limited.
Set<String> existingEmails = new Set<String>();
for(myObject__c obj :[SELECT Email__c FROM myObject__c WHERE Email__c IN :emailsToObjects.keySet()]){
    existingEmails.add(obj.Email__c);
}
```

Now, we can remove the records in `emailsToObjects` with an existing email.

```
emailsToObjects.keySet().removeAll(existingEmails);
```

Finally, we need to build a single list out of the remaining records.

```
// We need to iterate over all of the lists in our map.
// A nested for loop would work, but we can make use of the List class's
// addAll() method to avoid that.
List<myObject__c> recordsToInsert = new List<myObject__c>();
for(String email :emailsToObjects.keySet()){
    recordsToInsert.addAll(emailsToObjects.get(email));
}

insert recordsToInsert;
```

Comment: thanks Derek for your valuable  comment. i thinks this is the best way to solve my problem. thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
List< myObject__c> myObjectList = (list< myObject__c>)JSON.deserialize(yourJSON,myObject__c);
insert myObjectList;
```

Comment: -1 from me. This doesn't answer the question being asked, which is (in my best interpretation) "how do I insert records, excluding some arbitrary emails?"

Comment: You are right! Thanks for -1. @derek